# Can numbers be added at the end of menuitem in NavigationView?

Tags: android, menuitem, navigationview

I'm using NavigationView for create a drawer menu replacing my old ListView.

This is my current work.

[image]

But my old drawer menu has a number after each MenuItem (red rectangle area in the image).

Do NavigationView have a way to do this too?

Comment: No, For that thing stick to you old list view.

Comment: you can use app:actionLayout to do so read here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html

Answer (score 1):

No you can't! Right now implementing `NavigationView` using `DesignLibrary` don't support for adding custom items to the list. So you could wait for the update with fix else revert back and use custom `NagigationDrawer` using `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

Comment: It's okay. Now i'm heading back to ListView. Thank you for your information. :)